# How do you run javascript in the browser without dev-tools or bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, bookmarks

I like to make little scripts to do things on websites, but my school has progressively blocked the ability to do this on my Chromebook.

I usually used dev tools, but then it got blocked. Then I used "javascript:" in bookmarks, but they blocked that. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: chrome extension maybe?

Comment: they blocked those too

Comment: There are no other methods.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to run javascript on web pages, like changing variables and things.